# How to leave out of FOR EACH statement in Progress?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I am struggling with getting only first 2 records from a table via `FOR EACH`.
My goal is to read only first 2 records from a table, and save one field value to the variables.

Let's say I have the table `MyTable` with fields `PartNr`, `CreationDate`, `Company`, `ID`.

My `FOR EACH` statement would look like this:

```
FOR EACH MyTable
   WHERE MyTable.Company = "TestCompany"
      AND MyTable.CreationDate >= 01.01.2021
   NO-LOCK:
   
END.
```

That FOR EACH statement would find 15 records for example. I however only need the first two.
I would like to store the `PartNr` of the `first` record in a variable, and the `PartNr` of the `second` record in another variable.

After that the `FOR EACH` statement should end.

I have tried using `FIND FIRST` as well, but I don't know how to get the second record then.

I am pretty much looking for a `python` equivalent of `break` keyword when using `loops`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Quite amusing how the title of your question contains the answer :-) https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-reference-122/page/LEAVE-statement.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DEFINE VARIABLE iCounter AS INTEGER NO-UNDO . 

myLoop:
FOR EACH MyTable
   WHERE MyTable.Company = "TestCompany"
      AND MyTable.CreationDate >= 01.01.2021
   NO-LOCK:
   
   iCounter = iCounter + 1 . 

   IF iCounter = 2 THEN 
      LEAVE myLoop . 

END.
```

Comment: You can also add `WHILE iCounter < 2` to the `FOR EACH` statement.

Comment: @nwahmaet +100, while ``leave`` has its uses, I find that it breaks the natural flow, nearly as badly as a``goto`` statement. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If it really is a finite number of iterations that you know in advance, and if you are doing different logic based on the record you're up to, then you could also use a static query. It might make for cleaner code.

Something like this:

```
OPEN QUERY qMyQuery 
    FOR EACH MyTable
       WHERE MyTable.Company = "TestCompany"
         AND MyTable.CreationDate >= 01.01.2021
         NO-LOCK. 
         
QUERY qMyQuery:GET-FIRST. 

QUERY qMyQuery:GET-NEXT. 

CLOSE QUERY qMyQuery.
```